# Hotkey for IE11 tabs in metro / modern / touch mode

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys, modern-ui, internet-explorer-11

Is there a Hotkey for the tabs button in IE11 in metro / modern /touch mode?

Having to slide out the menu and click it is somewhat burdensome and would love a shortcut. (I am aware of ctrl+# for specific tabs)

[image: See button in question]

Screenshot for clarity, this is the button I am looking for a Hotkey for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While IE defines keyboard shortcuts for [many operations](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/ie-keyboard-shortcuts#ie=ie-11), the Tabs button doesn't seem to be one of them.

From what I can tell, the closest you can get (besides the ones you've already mentioned) is Ctrl+Tab, which cycles through each open tab in turn.  (Ctrl+Shift+Tab does this in reverse order.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

P.S.  Thanks for the edit, but I've found it easiest to keep things text based, especially for those not using GUI-based browsers.  Also, I sign my posts for transparency.  Thanks!